# How to implement Pace with ASP.Net MVC applications

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, pace

I have implemented `pace.js` with my ASP.NEt application so that I can display loading while my program performs `ajax` calls.

I have the following in my main layout view:

```
<script data-pace-options='{ "ajax": true, "elements": false, "document": false }' src="~/Scripts/pace.min.js"></script>
```

Unfortunately,

The loader keeps loading no matter what I do, sometimes it just goes on for ages. All I want it to do is load during my ajax calls. And it still loads even on pages that don't have ajax calls.

How do I do that?